# How can I make XCode indent // characters when I set a line to commented?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I indent some lines of code in XCode, it always puts the slash characters at the very beginning of the line, prior to indentation.

Before:

```
    if(0 == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Some line of code");
        NSLog(@"Another line of code");
    }
```

After:

```
    if(0 == 0) {
//        NSLog(@"Some line of code");
        NSLog(@"Another line of code");
    }
```

What I want it to do instead is put the "//" characters AFTER the indentation, like all other text editors on earth, like this:

```
    if(0 == 0) {
        //NSLog(@"Some line of code");
        NSLog(@"Another line of code");
    }
```

How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no option in Xcode to change this but you can install the **Comment Here** Xcode extension from the App Store that will do exactly what you are asking. Just install it and follow the easy instructions to set it up. It has worked great for me!

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/comment-here/id1406737173?mt=12

Answer (score -2):

1. "command [" until your text is attached to the left
2. add "//" (command /)
3. finally "command ]" to the original location.